# "Operational Error" when running coverage test

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I got a problem when running a coverage test in my django project, an operational error saying that a database already exists, I tried using fake migration

```
python manage.py migrate <appname> --fake
```

This is the error message I see

```
File "c:\users\ziad hossain\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "driver_driver_customer" already exists
```

Comment: Never run `migrate --fake` unless you really know what you're doing, it can completely mess up the state of your migrations. Anyway, you should show us the error you got during the coverage test.

Comment: I think the command is python manage.py migrate --fake <appname> you can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south for version > 1.8

Answer (score 3):

If you have the table created in the database, you can run `python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>` before using this I would suggest to check the Django version . You may use `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`. For version <= 1.8 refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/ for greater versions you will find --fake missing in documents https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for the above would be to go through the migrations folder and check why is django trying to create a Model that already exits.

1. First go to the migrations directory like **myapp/migrations/**
2. Do a grep on your table name on those .py files. Check if anything like this is present.

   ```
       migrations.CreateModel(
              name='driver_driver_customer',
              fields=[
   ```
3. Remove the file containing the above (including the respective .pyc file). Now do makemigrations and check if it showing something like

   ```
             - Create Table driver_driver_customer
   ```

   if not apply migrations.
4. If the same issues persists again, take a backup of the migrations folder, and remove all the files except **__init__.py** and **__init__.pyc**. Now apply migrations it should work.